# ¿Como adaptar un slider en responsive sin perder calidad?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy trabajando un diseño web, el cual le adapte un slider al inicio, en pantallas de equipos de computo se ven bien, pero en dispositivos móviles o responsive el slider se hace pequeño,quise adaptarlo que se vea completo pero se distorsiona y se mira feo,lo que no he logra es que se vea una parte que por lo regular que enfoque lo del medio de las imágenes.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.w-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/10/17/39/market-3466906_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/02/20/13/grocery-1232944_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/23/14/56/bazaar-1853361_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que me doy cuenta, la imagen se ve muy estirada en dispositivos pequeños, esto se debe a que le estás dando una **altura fija**, y por más pequeña que sea la pantalla, la altura de esa imagen **seguirá siendo la misma**. Para solucionar esto, puedes darle sólo un ancho del 100% a la imagen y ya no una altura fija, para que la imagen ocupe el ancho máximo de la pantalla:

```
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

También, éstas propiedades hacen que las flechas del carousel estén mal posicionadas, yo las quité y ahora se centran en la imagen:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

Código completo:

```css
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide m-5" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/10/17/39/market-3466906_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/02/20/13/grocery-1232944_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/23/14/56/bazaar-1853361_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Puedes ver mejor el resultado [**aquí**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/rNrgVqm).