# ¿Cómo lograr ocultar un menú al dar clic en alguna opción?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy creando un menú adaptable a dispositivos móviles. Para modo escritorio todo perfecto, pero al momento de hacerlo responsiva, al dar clic al ícono hamburguesa, me arroja bien las opciones; lo que quiero es que al dar clic en alguna opción vuelva a ocultarse el ícono.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="informacion">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>

      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
        desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual
        al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem
        Ipsum.
        <br> ¿Por qué lo usamos? Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal
        de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto
        por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras
        veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
      </p>
    </div>
    < </section>

      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por cierto, ¿ _vuelva a ocultarse el ícono_ o _vuelva a ocultarse el menú_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero agregué el evento `onclick` en cada uno de tus opciones (etiquetas `a`) para indicar que al hacer clic, llamemos a la función `cerrar()`:

```
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Inicio</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion" onclick="cerrar()">Conócenos</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Producto</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Servicios</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Contacto</a>
```

Y en la función, solo cogemos a la clase del botón del desplegable y le asignamos el método `click()` para que se haga clic en el botón automáticamente, y así se oculta el desplegable:

```
function cerrar() {
  let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");
  navbar.click();
}
```

---

Código:

```js
function cerrar() {
  let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");
  navbar.click();
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion" onclick="cerrar()">Conócenos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Producto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Contacto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section id="informacion">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Información</h1>
        <p>
          ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
          desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual
          al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem
          Ipsum.
          <br> ¿Por qué lo usamos? Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal
          de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto
          por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras
          veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que quería realizar, ya que JavaScript con sus funciones lo he tenido en el olvido, gracias de antemano amigo.

Comment: A usted, por cierto, me interesa saber si mi respuesta de esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582068/como-adaptar-un-slider-en-responsive-sin-perder-calidad) le sirvió, si es así, no olvides de también verificarla, saludos.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta amigo lo ando verificando, ya que el archivo lo tengo entro equipo, lo verifico y le comento.

Comment: Estuve validando que cuando estoy en modo escritorio hace como refresh al dar clic en los item

Answer (score 3):

Sin necesidad de incorporar JS adicional, es posible lograr esto agregando a cada `li` los atributos `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"`, los cuales son proporcionados por el propio Bootstrap.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="informacion">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>

      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
        desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual
        al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem
        Ipsum.
        <br> ¿Por qué lo usamos? Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal
        de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto
        por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras
        veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si ya vi que también funciona amigo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estuve validando tu respuesta pero para enlazar las href no funciona.

Comment: ¿Por qué lo decís @Miguel? ¿Qué no funciona?

Comment: La función de ocultar al dar clic en las opciones del menú si funciona, pero no alcanza a llamar los elementos <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>

Answer (score 0):

Hola vengo a decirles como me funciona a mi de manera fácil, lo pueden intentar.
Solo tienes que colocar esto en las etiquetas `<li>` y ya esta.

```
      <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Producto</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Servicios</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
      </li>
```

Codigo

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
  <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" >
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
         </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="informacion">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>

      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta)
        desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual
        al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem
        Ipsum.
        <br> ¿Por qué lo usamos? Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal
        de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto
        por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras
        veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
      </p>
    </div>
    < </section>

      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Evitando el parpadeo al estar en modo escritorio valido para BS5 ,se puede usar el siguiente script

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item:not(.dropdown)'); 
const menuToggle = document.getElementById('idDelNavbar'); 
const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle: false}); 

navLinks.forEach( function(l) { l.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (menuToggle.classList.contains('show')) { bsCollapse.toggle(); } });
     });
```